# Best way to escape % before inserting it on MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am having an issue on inserting this string

```
input: GyYu4$%acV
posted string: GyYu4$�V

Query error: Incorrect string value: '\xACV' for column.
```

It seems the best I get is `str_replace`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757812/codeigniter-best-practice-to-sanitize-input

Comment: you need to check character set of table and escaping for non-utf8 character

Answer (score 0):

I got the best escape for the issue its about escaping the non-utf8 character that @developerCK mentioned. its `utf8_encode`